# Can i install .net framework 4.0 on a system which has framework 3.5 already

Tags: .net, asp.net

We have a server which has .net framework 3.5 applications (asp.net & .net) running on it . And currently we are developing an application in .net framework 4.0 and we have to deploy this to the server.
Can we install .net framework 4.0 and 3.5 on the same system . And without recompiling or upgrading the existing applications. Please advise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can definitely install .NET 4 on the same machine. It shouldn't be a problem at all. Try it on a test server first in case you're doing anything unusual :)

(In particular, I don't know whether IIS application pools are automatically upgraded to .NET 4, or how that would affect your .NET 3.5 apps.)

Comment: Existing appPools are left alone and another is added as far as I can remember.

Comment: @Chris: That would make sense. It's the kind of thing I'd still check on a test server though :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Multiple versions of the Framework can be installed and you will be able to leave your current code as is, or convert it to 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.. you can have lots of different versions of the framework, and target different versions from VS. In the properties of a project you have the choice of setting a target framework, so you can build for different versions easily.

If you don't use features that are not available it's possible to build the same solution for different frameworks.